# Angular 2 XHR Post Not Executing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but a simple http.post in the `createPost` method doesn't seem to be executing.

I have set breakpoints in the .NET backend and they don't get hit in the debugger.   The curious thing is if I use postman with the URL I log to the console, it works just fine, so I have narrowed it down to the TypeScript Method.   Other methods such as getting all posts work fine as well.

If I add a `subscribe()` to the the `createPost` method, it says `Subscription` is not valid because `_isScalar` is not set.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
//post-form.component.ts.   First link in the chain.   Calls this.postService.save()      
save() {
          if (this.model.title && this.model.body) {
              this.saving = true;
              this.postsService.save(this.model)
                  .then((res) => {
                      console.log(res);
                  })
                  .then(() => this.saving = false);

      }
  }

//posts.service.ts.  //2nd link in the chain.   calls the createPost method.
save(post: Post) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!post.postId) {
            console.log('Waypoint 34');
            post.state = post.state ? post.state : 'unsaved';
            this.createPost(post)
                .map(

                res => resolve(res)
                );
        } else {
            let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
            this.http.put(environment.api + '/posts/save', post, options)
        }
    })
}


createPost(newPost: Post): Observable<ResponseResult>  { // problem child.
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    console.log(environment.api + '/posts'); //gets here.
    return this.http.post(environment.api + '/posts', newPost, options)
        .map(this.helpers.extractData)  //doesn't get here.
        .catch(this.helpers.handleError);
}

//helpers.service.ts

  extractData(res: Response) {
      let body = res.json();
      return body.data || body ||  {};
  }
```

**EDIT** Called out which method is not executing (createPost), further annotated code and added helpers.extractData (from John Papa)

Comment: Which method is not working? `createPost`? Also, can you add the code for `this.helpers.extractData`?

Comment: Thanks for bringing that glaring omission to my attention, fixed.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what a POST to o`environment.api + '/posts'` returns?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that while createPost returns an Observable as long as it's not subscribed to it will not start executing. Instead of calling map after calling createPost you will need to switch that to a subscribe call, as you are finished with the Observable.

```
this.createPost(post)
            .subscribe (
                res => resolve(res)
            );
```

I would suggest further reading on hot and cold observables.

Comment: I tried that and I get an error `_isscalar is missing in type subscription`